# How to resize a Bootstrap Modal with a Carousel inside that has differing sized images, smoothly

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a carousel inside of a modal...
The carousel cycles through the images, but I have a video in there, so the sizing changes when I reach the video.
However, when the modal/carousel gets to the video from a picture (vice-versa) it has a horrible clunky resize.
I would like a smooth transition between the sizes.
Can anyone help
P.s we cant define sizes in pixels as this must work with a variety of sizes

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                    <h3 id="myModalLabel">So, Why Are We The Best?</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade">
                        <!-- Carousel items -->
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="active item">
                            <div class="video">
                                <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=640177702674225"></iframe>
                                </div>
                                <hr></hr>
                                <p>Description</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="img/Comp_1.jpg">
                                <hr></hr>
                                <p>Description</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="img/Comp_2.jpg">
                                <hr></hr>
                                <p>Description</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="img/Comp_3.jpg">
                                <hr></hr>
                                <p>Description</p>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <!-- Carousel nav -->
                        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: put it inside jsFiddle so that i can edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [bootstrap-modal-carousel](http://noreiller.github.io/bootstrap-modal-carousel/modal-carousel.html) this might be helpful